# mex -I flag not finding include files in a separate directory

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, mex

Running into another MATLAB mex file related issue.

Currently trying to automatically generate mex files from .cpp files in a given directory given the paths to said directories.

Currently my command looks soft of like this...

```
% These are getting passed in, but I verified the contents %
input = 'C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\src\something\util\sequence\sequence.cpp'
mexDir = 'C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\mex'
includeDir = 'C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\include\something\util\sequence\'

eval(['mex ' input ' -outdir ' mexDir ' -I' includeDir])

which looks like...
'mex C:/Users/ian/libXYZ/src/something/util/sequence/Sequence.cpp -outdir C:/Users/ian/libXYZ/mex -IC:/Users/ian/libXYZ/include/something/util/sequence/'
```

For some strange reason, I get an error with includes in the first file we hit.

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Professional'.
Error using mex
Sequence.cpp
C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\src\something\util\sequence\Sequence.cpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
'something/util/sequence/Sequence.hpp': No such file or directory
```

It errors out when it looks for the include file. I double checked that the '/' vs '\' wasn't doing it (I used strrep(x, '\', '/') on the paths and tried it again to check) and made sure that the files were there, the paths were correct, and that the .cpp file had the correct includes. All of these are not the issue after some extensive testing and playing around with it.

The question would be, why does the -Ipathname flag in the eval(mex) call not allow the compiler to grab the correct include directory?

If anyone has any ideas as to why this might be happening, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT : 
This is the line which includes Sequence.hpp in Sequence.cpp

```
// Include project headers
#include "something/util/sequence/Sequence.hpp"
```

There might be weirdness here, but I'm not sure how to check or how to solve it (absolute vs relative paths?).

Comment: If you just type it instead of using eval? If you move the directory to somewhere else (perhaps permission problems)?

Comment: No, same issue. I think it might have something to do with the way in which the #include statement is written. I'll edit the question and add that line in Sequence.cpp.

Comment: Set include directory as `'C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\include'`.

Comment: That seems like a C++ problem then ;). If I am not wrong, `#include "header"` means look in the local directory for the header. Because you may be compiling from somewhere else than `C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\src\`, then you may have a problem there

Comment: @rahnema1 Thanks! That did it. So I guess it was weirdness with the paths. My bad for missing something that easy :P

Comment: @AndersBiguri Thanks! That's exactly the issue.

Comment: @AndersBiguri Do you know what the exact reason for why it breaks if given the absolute path?

Comment: Concatenate the directory path with the filename that is in the error message you can get the correct filename. `C:\Users\ian\libXYZ\include` + `something/util/sequence/Sequence.hpp`

Comment: @Ian the `#include` statement did not have an absolute path. Still, just have a look at how to structure a C++ project, because there are ways of doing this properly, else you may find yourself with more problems down the line